# How to call a bootstrap modal store in one JSP page from another JSP Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I have a JSP page which contain the whole modal say modal structure (header,body and footer).
The page is like below

```
<% @ page language = "java" contentType = "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding = "ISO-8859-1"
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

And I also have another JSP page where on clicking on a button **Open Modal**, the modal with ID **myModal** store in the above JSP page will be open.The current page will be intact, additionally a modal popup will be open on it.
Here is The Page from where I'll call the modal

```
<% @ page language = "java" contentType = "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding = "ISO-8859-1"
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Modal Example</h2>
            <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How I get this?

Answer (score 0):

If the modal's HTML isn't rendered on the page you cannot do it without ajax. You would need to create an ajax function which will get only modal's HTML code and put it somewhere in the current body (using jquery's append probably), and then you can show it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your moal code would need to be *just* a div and stuff, you don't want to try and include a whole other html document inside your code.

You'd want to include that file, either via import or include into the scope of your page you want to use the modal on, then in js, do `$("#myModal").modal('show')`